# How best to read XML HttpClient responses as a stream in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, multithreading, httpclient

I'm having a problem doing multi-threaded HttpClient calls and reading the XML responses as streams.
I have an application that creates one or more HttpClient calls, each in its own thread, and reads the response as a stream, using the **HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead** option.
These streams are then used by an XMLReader to parse the response XML, as it is returned.

Here's the code:

```
HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
HttpResponseMessage r = await client.SendAsync(hrm, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
Stream stream = await r.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
XmlReaderSettings xmlRS = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlRS.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlRS))
{
   while (xmlReader.ReadState != ReadState.Closed)
   {
      if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("HOST"))
      {                                  
         XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
         waitingXDocs.Enqueue(xdoc);                                 
      }
      Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
 }
 stream.Dispose();
```

waitingXDocs is a ConcurrentQueue object.
This code works fine when a single HttpClient.SendAsync() call is running at a time (single-threaded) but when more than one of these threads is running, the xmlReader, and by extension, the stream, contain the same data.
Although I don't show it here, the URI contains parameters which are different for each thread.
This setup works perfectly fine if I use the HttpClient.PostAsync() method and wait for the entire response to return before parsing it;  I've run 10 or more threads that way without an issue.  But that uses alot of memory and wasted time, waiting before the parsing can begin.

Putting aside the fact I'm mixing XMLReader and XDocument objects, is there a reason this shouldn't work?  Why would the streams to multiple HttpClient responses return the same data?
I've verified that the stream and xmlReader objects point to different memory addresses across all of the threads, so the references aren't accidentally pointing to the same objects in multiple threads.

Comment: A cookie is being used.  When you setup the first connection the cookie is established and then the second time the same cookie is being used.  So you get same results.

Comment: I should point out that I'm using a different/new HttpClient object for each thread.  I *believe* that goes against standard practice but using a single object was extremely slow for me, when I was using HttpClient.PostAsync().

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The server recognizes the IP address of client and associates a cookie with the IP address.  The cookie is stored in the user temporary folder.  So there is already an association between the client IP address and the server.

Comment: This seems to work ok if I wait for the entire response from HttpClient before parsing the XML.  I can multi-thread there with no problems.  But, for some reason, when I try to parse the response, as it arrives, I get this problem.

Comment: You do not need the while loop.  Just :             using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlRS))
            {
                xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("HOST");
                if (!xmlReader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement host = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }